# Regulating Gas Flow to a Cooktop

Tags: stove, gas, propane-cooktop

What options do the best cooktops (or complete gas stoves) have to regulate gas flow in cases of variable gas source pressure?

For example, I don't want my cooking to be affected when the furnace in my house switches on (which would reduce the gas flow to my stove if it simply used a partially-open mechanical valve).

I could imagine an expensive cooktop with some feedback mechanism to make sure gas flow is constant, or even to maintain some measured temperature, but I have never seen such a thing.  Is feedback ever used?

Comment: I'm not sure this wouldn't be better on https://diy.stackexchange.com/ or even https://law.stackexchange.com/ but if your house is so seriously under-gassed [& you can't get redress from the relevant authorities] then you **must** reduce the 'greed' of the appliance that 'steals' from the rest - otherwise one day something will explode.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more an engineering problem than cooking.